# Changing font size for Seaborn pairplot

Tags: python, seaborn

I have created a scatter matrix using pandas, in a Jupyter notebook. It's a 12x12 matrix, so it takes up a lot of space and, therefore, the x- and y- ticks and labels are quite small.

I found code to increase the size for pandas' `scatter_matix`.

```
from pandas.plotting import scatter_matrix

Axes = scatter_matrix(df, figsize=(14, 14), diagonal='kde')
#y ticklabels
[plt.setp(item.yaxis.get_majorticklabels(), 'size', 7) for item in Axes.ravel()]
#x ticklabels 
# ...

#y labels
[plt.setp(item.yaxis.get_label(), 'size', 10) for item in Axes.ravel()]
```

I want to compare the same plot in Seaborn

```
grid = sns.pairplot(df,  diag_kind='kde')
```

but I can't figure out how to change the font sizes. I can't call `ravel` on a `PairGrid`. Is there something similar?

I've been looking at possible posts here in S.O. but nothing seems to work.

Is here a Seaborn equivalent to

```
[plt.setp(item.yaxis.get_label(), 'size', 10) for item in Axes.ravel()]
```

[image]

Comment: Replace `Axes.ravel()` by `grid.axes.ravel()`?

Answer (score 2):

Default is 1, can change to bigger scale.

```
sns.set(font_scale=val)
```